# Laravel - what do I have to upload to production?

Tags: laravel, upload, development-environment, production-environment

I have my site online and am developing locally. Once the changes are made, I upload the changed files to the production site. This includes obviously controllers, routes file, views, providers, policies etc... but there are 2 situations that are not entirely clear to me:

1) if I make changes to the app.js and recompile, do I only have to upload the compiled  file in the public folders, or do I have to upload the sources too?

2) if I locally install a new package, for example this (my current situation): `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\CookieConsent\CookieConsentServiceProvider" --tag="lang"`, what files and folders do I have to update?

Comment: what way are you upload file to production? Are using git or else? what about your production environment?

Comment: Personally I prefer deploying the source files only i.e. excluding vendor and compiled assets and then run the `composer install` and `npm run dev/prod` on the server. This is mostly because these are the files that are checked in source control and it's easier to deploy by run a simple script that does a checkout and runs those commands. however its entirely up to you how you deploy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Answer to your question.

1. You need to upload just compiled file if you haven't any processes to compile file after upload
2. You need to upload files that create your `vendor:publish` in your case, it will be language files generated. Also, you will need to do composer install on your server if it's not in your deployment process already

In general Its easier to use other deployment tools rather than uploading manually. 
At least you can use git on your server to pull changes.

Comment: thank you.. i currently upload manually to the FTP.. I've never used deployment tools.. will look into it.. do you happen to have a good read on hand?

Comment: here is a good read for deploying laravel application: https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-deploy-laravel-projects-to-live-server-the-ultimate-guide/
Here is some payed services to do deployments: https://www.sitepoint.com/lets-compare-runcloud-vs-forge-vs-serverpilot/
There are number of tools like https://deployer.org/ or https://capistranorb.com/ etc

Comment: So you mean that `npm run prod` must be run only when deploying the server and only is needed to update the latest `app.js` file that results from recompiling assets? Same applies to new packages? Thank you.